# J query scroller asp.net

Tags: jquery

I have to make a jquery scroller as given in http://www.isango.com/. Look at the bottom of the site. Please Help me making this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugin options out there for this, you can just format the navigation however you want.  The closest I can think of is [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html), check out their [very similar demo here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/navigator.html).

The plugin that the site is *actually* using is the [Step Carousel Veiwer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm) with some customization, but the jQuery tools version is closer to the UI they have than the base version of the plugin that they're using :)

Comment: Thank you very much all of you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Carousel control. There are many around, but I personally like [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) as it's lightweight yet flexible.